# Creating new chunks in ItemWriter

Tags: spring-batch

I need to conditionally execute multiple INSERTs/UPDATEs against multiple tables in my ItemWriter for each item in the chunk.

I have come up with the below code for my CustomItemWriter. The output from processor is a complex object. The write method contains some business logic to prepare a list for rows to INSERT/UPDATE against each table based on the contents of the input item. I create new chunks from these lists and feed these chunks to the respective writers.

This code does seem to be working fine. My question is whether creating so many lists/new chunks is the right approach? Is there is a more idiomatic way of dealing with multiple INSERTS/UPDATEs against multiple tables in the ItemWriter?

```
public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<CustEnriched> {
 
   //writers
    private final JdbcBatchItemWriter<CustRequest> custRequestWriter;
    private final JdbcBatchItemWriter<CustEarn> custEarnWriter;
    private final JdbcBatchItemWriter<CustEligible> custEligWriter;
    private final JdbcBatchItemWriter<CustEligible> custTargetWriter;

    public void write(Chunk<? extends CustEnriched> chunk) throws Exception {
        //lists to accumulate rows/writer
        List<CustRequest> custRequestChunkList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<CustEarn> custEarnChunkList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<CustEligible> custEligChunkList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<CustEligible> custTargetChunkList = new ArrayList<>(); 
       
        for (CustEnriched item : chunk.getItems()) {
           
            //build methods contain logic to convert the item into one or more rows to be INSERTED/UPDATED per item
            
            custRequestChunkList.addAll(buildCustRequestList(item));
            custEarnChunkList.addAll(buildCustEarnList(item));
            custEligChunkList.add(buildCustEligible(item));

            if (!item.getEligibleForTarge().isEmpty()) {
                custTargetChunkList.add(buildCustTarget(item));
            }
        }
        
        //creating new chunks populated with respective lists from above & feeding to writers
        custRequestWriter.write(new Chunk<>(dedupList(custRequestChunkList)));
        custEarnWriter.write(new Chunk<>(custEarnChunkList));
        custEligWriter.write(new Chunk<>(custEligChunkList));
        custTargetWriter.write(new Chunk<>(custTargetChunkList));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html)? This item writer uses a `Classifier` to classify items and delegate the write operation to a specific item writer. The classification of items can be based on a criteria of the item, its type, etc (take a look at the classifiers provided by Spring Retry here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/tree/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/classify).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine The ClassifierCompositeItemWriter documentation indicates that it "Calls one of a collection of ItemWriters for each item".. For my use case i have to call multiple ItemWriters for every single item eg. For item 1, i might have to insert 5 records into Table A (ItemWriter1), 15 records into Table B (ItemWriter2) & update 1 record in Table C (ItemWriter 3). For item 2, i might have to insert records into a different set of tables - each with its own itemWriter. Your thoughts? Is there anything wrong in the way i have currently implemented the write method?

Comment: OK I see, then the composite writer is not what you need. It seems that the custom writer you came up with is "dictated" by your requirement (so there is not much you can do differently, other than probably encapsulate the lists in an aggregate item and do the preparation in the processor).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thank you for your response. The reason i am doing this logic in the writer is because each INSERT requires a sequence # that i need to fetch from a db sequence object. To optimize calls against DB, i am fetching all sequences required for the entire chunk (num sequences can vary from chunk to chunk) in a single db call in the writer and then populating those sequence # for each model object sent to individual item writers.. i dont want to pack model objects in processor in lists and again unpack them in writer because i need to add seq.. Does that make sense? :)

Comment: It does. I don't know the original requirement, but my hunch when a step is "difficult" to implement is that it is probably doing too much. Anyway, if that works for you, then go for it.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thank you, sir! One last thing.. I havent seen many examples of people creating new chunks explicitly in the writer like i am (new Chunk<>(custEarnChunkList)).. Is there anything wrong in creating chunks this way Or is there a better way?

Comment: if you need to call delegates writers with new data, then you have to create new chunks like you shared, I don't see another way to do it.